# Mac OS X Sierra installation stuck in a reboot loop

Tags: install, startup, restore, macos, error

I tried updating my system from El Capitan to Mac Sierra. This is my Macbook Pro configuration:

[image: My Configuration]

Somewhere around 90% of the installation...

[image: Installation in Progress]

...this message appeared on the screen:

[image: Message]

Then, the computer restarted and got back to the installation from around 50% quickly to 90% and got stuck again on the same message attached above.
After 6-7 cycles of auto reboots this appeared on the screen...

[image]

...after which the computer shut itself down.

When I turned it back on, the same story went again all the way until it shuts down.

Since I couldn’t get Sierra to install I decided to restore my El Capitan from Time Machine. I turned the computer on, pressed and held the ALT key to enter boot menu, selected the Time Machine, but it didn’t start restoring but restarted and got to the **same aforementioned loop** until the shut down.

I tried resetting PRAM, holding CMD+R upon power on to enter the reinstall menu, but I still couldn’t reach/activate Time Machine to start with the restore.

Then, somewhere in between these loops, I forced the shut down by holding the power button and restarted and only then it offered me a different kind of menu with 3 options (Install Sierra, Restore from Time Machine, and Disk Utility) where I finally got Time Machine to starts restoring.

Now, I did this process of trying to install Sierra and restoring to the El Capitan **TWICE** to make sure it’s not some random stuff. It definitely isn’t.

**What should I do to install Mac OS X Sierra? How can I avoid this being stuck in a reboot loop?**

Comment: Error message image is missing.. We also don't need the opinion at the end; if there is something wrong with your original data/structure, then restoring it & trying again will not make it any better... repeating the same experiment & expecting different results is an Einsteinian error.

Comment: Instead of restoring from Time Machine, have you tried to wipe your partition and do a clean install?

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, I’ve removed my personal opinions. Although I’ve removed the error message reference as well I disagree with your reasoning — What I’ve been referring to as error message is the 3rd message I posted and as a USER I am interpreting this not only merely as information, but also error because “a problem” is referred to. From a UX perspective this is an error message.

Comment: @Tetsujin I strongly disagree with your Einsteinian comparison. I’ve been repeating many experiments with Apple and got different results many times, so I don’t think your reasoning is entirely applicable in this case, thanks.

Comment: @Allan I’m trying to avoid this scenario so I don’t have to reinstall and setup a ton of software from scratch. However, if the problem persists, that will turn out as inevitable, it seems. Thanks.

Comment: @Tetsujin I forgot to ask, how do you know that something is wrong with my original data/structure? I did the usual First Aid on the hard drive to check for any errors, but everything went fine. Can you provide me on some information how to check this more thoroughly? Thanks.

Comment: It's to test things out.  Right now, you are in a loop that dosen't install.  If a clean install causes the same problem, it's likely hardware.  If not, then you know you have a problem with your TM backup.  It's called *diagnosis*

Comment: @Allan got it, makes sense. However, as I already mentioned above, I DID manage to restore El Capitan from my Time Machine twice already so I’m assuming the Time Machine backup is fine, although your proposition stands in any case.

Comment: Have you tried "verbose mode"  When your install restarts, hold down Cmd-V for verbose mode.  See where it crashes.

Comment: As a matter of fact I haven’t. I will try that, thank you very much @Allan.

Comment: Ok, after no solution and relictance to wipe out all my apps and start from scratch I decided to go the service. It turned out the kernel panick screen was indeed an indication that something may be wrong with the hardware so they did full hardware diagnostics and luckily everything went fine… TBC.

Comment: …Then they succsessfully updated the OS to Sierra HOWEVER they were able to update it before any of the programs were loaded that might have taken some ports. Also, since they are Apple certified service, they have access to the update directly from Apple servers, different than the ones served from App Store. As a conclusion they told me this means two things:

Comment: Either the update got stuck due to internet connection, either some of the apps I had was blocking the ports. And since it is true I have a ton of apps, it’s quite likely that this was the case.

Comment: Now, I’m not sure whether I should have posted this in the answer section or in the comment. I decided I comment it first. @Tetsujin, your suggestions are welcome. Thanks.