# Finally reinstalled macOS Sierra, but now I get a kernel panic

Tags: macos, startup, kernel-panic

I got stuck in an endless loop trying to reinstall macOS Sierra but after following Monomeeth's advice in this question: [Stuck in endless macOS Sierra installation loop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/286189/240852) I was able to get it installed.

But now I get a kernel panic when booting up. I do not understand kernel panics and did a Google search and read this question/answer: [What is a Kernel Panic and what does it mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/199737/240852) but am none the wiser.

I cannot paste the kernel panic as it happens every time I now boot up, and only appears briefly, so here is a photo I took:
[image]

I see that it says `Mac OS version: Not yet set`.

What does that mean? Is that my problem? Can anyone help me interpret this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A kernel panic is nothing more than a software crash. A bit like when an application quits for no apparent reason, except in this case, it brings down the entire system, since the kernel is the heart of the operating system. It looks like you weren't done with the installation, because it appears to be trying to continue the installation, but can't for some reason. I'd boot into recovery and reinstall from there by holding down <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>while booting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried this and got the exact same endless loop problem https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/286189/240852 I had before. Aargh!

Comment: Try holding down `command + alt + p + r` when booting.

Comment: If resetting NVRAM doesn't work (as suggested by @WilliamTFroggard above) then try booting with `command+option+r` instead. This will try the installation again via the internet, so you'll be prompted to connect to the internet after you see a spinning globe on the screen.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Resetting PRAM got me booted directly into the installation process, but after a while I got a message saying that macOS could not be installed on this computer and to reboot holding D key down to use Apple Diagnostics. I did this but after running the extended test no errors were found.

Comment: @Monomeeth If I do the command+option+r thing I end up in the same installation loop you helped me solve by creating the USB installer. Now what? I'm going around in circles here! :(

Comment: after the `command + alt + p + r`, and the computer reboots, immediately hold down "command + r" for recovery mode. See if that works.